# Difference between The Ring and Ringu

Tags: comparison, the-ring, ringu

I watched the Hollywood version of [The Ring (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298130/), but I didn't watch the original Japanese version [Ringu (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178868/). Are the plots of both movies exactly the same? If not, what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 6):

[*The Ring* (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298130/) is a remake of the Japanese horror film, [*Ringu* (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178868/). You can read summaries of both plots in Wikipedia by following links [*Ringu* (1998)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28film%29) and [*The Ring* (2002)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_%282002_film%29).

In general, both films are based on Koji Suzuki's novel *[Ring](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932234411)* and focus on a mysterious cursed videotape that contains a seemingly random series of disturbing images. So in most places movies are similar with little change and even the ending part is similar too.

The main difference I got from Wikipedia is that in *Ringu*, the reason for the curse is in history of the great psychic Shizuko Yamamura, whose astounding supernatural power was accused to be a fraud. Yamamura committed suicide for which and the power passed on to her daughter also made her distrusted by the world and ultimately, killed by her father. And that girl become the ghost.

In *The Ring*, the story is little different but otherwise the story follows the similar path.

[Here](http://blogcritics.org/ringu-vs-the-ring/) is a point to point difference from a viewer point of view.

Comment: Also, in Ringu it's explained why the little boy has psychic powers (he inherited it from his dad).

Comment: There is a Japanese Version?! Ah gotta watch that asap!

Comment: *The Ring* does not credit the screenplay of *Ringu*, but does anyone believe it is based on the book only?